# Result of the sum notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

What is the meaning of *T* and $q^{T}$? I've seen this notation many times, but I don't understand its meaning. Is it a power? or is it a vector? It should be just a number.

$R(q,u)=\sum_{N}^{i=1} q_{i}u_{i}=q^{T}u$

Comment: It is just a transposition. The transposition of a row vector is a column vector and vice versa.

Comment: why would this be a transposition? Isn't is just a number?

Comment: The $T$ is the transposition. $q^T$ means "q transposed". The sum results in a number (the dot product of $q$ and $u$, to be concrete)